# Connect Firebase with OutSystems

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, outsystems

I have a Firebase database and I'd like to connect it with an OutSystems platform.

I have tried following the [documentation](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/10/Extensibility_and_Integration/Connect_to_an_External_Database), however, Firebase is a NoSQL database from what I know. So which option do I choose for DBMS?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [this component](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/1406/) or [this other one](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component/2121/firebase-web/)?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Firebase via REST APIs.

The "connect to an external database" feature, you were trying to use only supports relational databases.